# Separate list of present and absent in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to separate table results into those who are present and absent. For example, I have this [users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Gx3.png) here and [user_attendance table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWEjA.png) here. Those users in the user_attendance table were present and I am trying to use the query below to show those who are not present/absent in the user_attendance table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user_attendance` 
    INNER JOIN users on users.user_id = user_attendance.user_id 
WHERE users.user_id IS NULL;
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: user_id never can be NULL with inner JOIN

Comment: @nbk sorry my bad

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry my bad, it should not be null but instead not exists which Benjamin D answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Absent
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_attendance WHERE user_attendance.user_id = users.user_id);
```

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to choose the answer (via the button) to show others the chosen solution

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from   users 
where  user_id not in(select user_id from user_attendance where user_id is not null)
```

| user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | john |
| 4 | jose |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SXuXD5_Y)